# Object is always empty when deserialize on xamarin service

Tags: json, xamarin, service, deserialization

Have this service built on a xamarin app:

```
public class OpenWeatherMap<T>
{
    private const string OpenWeatherApi = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";
    private const string Key = "653b1f0bf8a08686ac505ef6f05b94c2";

    HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

    // aqui podemos enviar directo a una ciudad hardcoded
    public async Task<T> GetAllWeathers(string city)
    {
        var json = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(OpenWeatherApi + city + "&APPID=" + Key);
        var getWeatherModels = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        return getWeatherModels;
    }
}
```

When i check the model object is always empty. JSON is fine and my class matches perfectly my JSON model. I'm using Newtonsoft.Json.

This is my model:

```
public class WeatherMainModel
{

    [JsonProperty("coord")]
    public Coord Coord { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("weather")]
    public WeatherSubDetails[] Weather { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("base")]
    public string Base { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("main")]
    public Main Main { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("visibility")]
    public string Visibility { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("wind")]
    public WeatherWindDetails Wind { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("clouds")]
    public Clouds Clouds { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("dt")]
    public string Dt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sys")]
    public WeatherSysDetails Sys { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cod")]
    public string Cod { get; set; }
}

public partial class Clouds // new
{
    [JsonProperty("all")]
    public string All { get; set; }
}

public partial class Coord // new
{
    [JsonProperty("lon")]
    public string Lon { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("lat")]
    public string Lat { get; set; }
}

public partial class Main
{
    [JsonProperty("temp")]
    public string Temp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("pressure")]
    public string Pressure { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("humidity")]
    public string Humidity { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("temp_min")]
    public string TempMin { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("temp_max")]
    public string TempMax { get; set; }
}

public partial class WeatherSysDetails
{
    [JsonProperty("type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("country")]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sunrise")]
    public string Sunrise { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("sunset")]
    public string Sunset { get; set; }
}

public partial class WeatherSubDetails
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("main")]
    public string Main { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("icon")]
    public string Icon { get; set; }
}

public partial class WeatherWindDetails
{
    [JsonProperty("speed")]
    public string Speed { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("deg")]
    public string Deg { get; set; }
}
```

I'm using visual studio community set for Latin America (Chile), so i tried changing every decimal field on the JSON to string on the model to avoid comma separation problems, but still, my object is coming empty no matter the JSON i inject to the deserializer. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the normal JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WeatherMainModel>(json) work?

Comment: No, is not working either. I found a post yesterday marked as answer explaining that newtonsoft json.net doesn't work when debugging on the xamarin live player and that's the way i've tested all the time. My emulator doesn't work so i used the live player app to test. I haven't found any other logical reason for this error so far.

Comment: I'll suggest you start with the specific deserialization, then once working you can implement the one with generics. Can't you fix the emulator or try on a physical device?

Comment: I'm fixing the emulator in order to test properly, i'll let you know when i'm ready. Thanks

Comment: I solved the problem. It was in fact a conflict between the live player and json.net package. Deployed perfect on the emulator. Thanks to everyone.